# how can I record the same number of massages from different topics?

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to build a database that takes each image with its joy and IMU (angles) data, so I need to receive the same number of messages for each topic to have a synchronized data.
I run the below command in order to record RGB images, depth images, joystick commands, and IMU data.

```
$> rosbag record -O subset /camera/depth/image_raw /camera/rgb/image_raw /joy /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw
```

then

```
 $> rosbag info subset.bag
```

which show me the information about my recorded bag file

> ```
> path:        subset.bag
> version:     2.0
> duration:    21.9s
> start:       Mar 11 2018 16:31:17.29 (1520771477.29)
> end:         Mar 11 2018 16:31:39.20 (1520771499.20)
> size:        857.5 MB
> messages:    3113
> compression: none [605/605 chunks]
> types:       sensor_msgs/Image [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
> ```

```
             sensor_msgs/Imu   [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2]
             sensor_msgs/Joy   [5a9ea5f83505693b71e785041e67a8bb]
```

> ```
> topics:      /camera/depth/image_raw             652 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
> ```

```
             /camera/rgb/image_raw               540 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
             /joy                                991 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Joy  
             /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw   930 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu
```

as you see there are a diffrente number of messegas for each topic. So, how can I receive the same number of it?
and one more thing

any help please?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285049/how-can-i-record-the-same-number-of-massages-from-different-topics?/) by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the documentation in the [ros wiki: rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline):

```
-l NUM, --limit=NUM
     Only record NUM messages on each topic.
```

This is however not(!) what you really want to use as you will most likely not record the imu-message that belongs to the image-data as the imu (probably) will have a much higher frequency. A [Time Synchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer) is a better choice.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-03-12**:
First of all, thank you for your replay.
Your first suggestion is works but it doesn't adequate because I don't know how many messages I need to accomplish the desired task.
could you help me please how can I use the time synchronizer in my case, cuz I'm new with both ROS and python!

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-03-12**:
The wiki page I linked already contains an example in python. Where exactly is your problem?

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-03-13**:
I saw the link but actually, I could not understand how should I use it. I run the python file but nothing is happening! I wonder if this file records my data or not? or what should I change on it? sorry if this show a stupid question but I just started with ROS&Python as well.any help is appreciate

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-04-11**:
@NEngelhard hello again! could you tell me please what should I put on `callback` function? should I record my data within callback function section? or I should read a previous recording bag file inside the callback function?